PointStack styled WMS: how to understand if the clicked feature is made of points all with same lat and lng
I've a layer styled with PointStack and I want to know when I click on a stacked marker, if the cluster is made by point with all the same lat and lng or not. So I'm trying to use the countunique properties in the GetFeatureInfo response but it seems to be always 1. How can I achive it?

GetFeatureInfo only works at a point (pixel coordinates) location.  It retrieves features at the location in the data underlying the map, at the clicked point up to the limit set by the FEATURE_COUNT={num}& value if specified, otherwise one, per query layer.

Yes, I know but in this case the query_layer is just one and the feature is one too (the cluster). The problem is that I have no access to what is inside the cluster. I thought there is a way to work around it. Thank you
